# how can i get hypernyms of multiple words using java

Tags: java, arraylist, wordnet, hypernym

I want to get "**hypernyms**"of multiple words using WordNet dictionary in java.

**What is Hypernyms?**a word with a broad meaning constituting a category into which words with more specific meanings fall; a superordinate. For example, colour is a hypernym of red.

So if we have following words
1) apple
2) banana
3) hepatitis
4) tree
5) mango

the desire output is that 
**Sense 1:**

**Apple**: -- (fruit with red or yellow or green skin and sweet to tart crisp whitish flesh)

=> edible fruit -- (edible reproductive body of a seed plant especially one having sweet flesh)

=> produce, green goods, green groceries, garden truck -- (fresh fruits and vegetable grown for the market)

=> food, solid food -- (any solid substance (as opposed to liquid) that is used as a source of nourishment; "food and drink")

=> solid -- (a substance that is solid at room temperature and pressure)

=> substance, matter -- (that which has mass and occupies space; "an atom is the smallest indivisible unit of matter")

=> physical entity -- (an entity that has physical existence)

=> entity -- (that which is perceived or known or inferred to have its own distinct existence (living or nonliving))

=> fruit -- (the ripened reproductive body of a seed plant)

=> reproductive structure -- (the parts of a plant involved in its reproduction)

=> plant organ -- (a functional and structural unit of a plant or fungus)

=> plant part, plant structure -- (any part of a plant or fungus)

=> natural object -- (an object occurring naturally; not made by man)

=> whole, unit -- (an assemblage of parts that is regarded as a single entity; "how big is that part compared to the whole?"; "the team is a unit")

=> object, physical object -- (a tangible and visible entity; an entity that can cast a shadow; "it was full of rackets, balls and other objects")

=> physical entity -- (an entity that has physical existence)

=> entity -- (that which is perceived or known or inferred to have its own distinct existence (living or nonliving))

=> pome, false fruit -- (a fleshy fruit (apple or pear or related fruits) having seed chambers and an outer fleshy part)

=> fruit -- (the ripened reproductive body of a seed plant)

=> reproductive structure -- (the parts of a plant involved in its reproduction)

=> plant organ -- (a functional and structural unit of a plant or fungus)

=> plant part, plant structure -- (any part of a plant or fungus)

=> natural object -- (an object occurring naturally; not made by man)

=> whole, unit -- (an assemblage of parts that is regarded as a single entity; "how big is that part compared to the whole?"; "the team is a unit")

=> object, physical object -- (a tangible and visible entity; an entity that can cast a shadow; "it was full of rackets, balls and other objects")

=> physical entity -- (an entity that has physical existence)

=> entity -- (that which is perceived or known or inferred to have its own distinct existence (living or nonliving))

Comment: Please clarify you objective. The question seems to abstract.

Comment: Sir the question is that i have a string s1 which contain 5 words, apple, mango, banana, tree and hepatitis. i want to get the hypernyms of all the words in a single code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is **hypernyms** ?

**Answer:** A word with a broad meaning constituting a category into which words with more specific meanings fall; a superordinate. For example, colour is a hypernym of red.

i am listing the code for extracting the hypernyms tree... it will give you the detailed tree of any word which is present in the **WordNet 3.0** dictionary.

Call this method

```
private static ArrayList<String> getHypernymTerm( PointerTargetNodeList ptnl,
                                                        ArrayList<String> parent2, String str )  
            throws JWNLException{
      ArrayList<String> parent = parent2;
      if ( !str.equals("entity") ) {
        for (Iterator<?> itr = ptnl.iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
          PointerTargetNode node = (PointerTargetNode) itr.next();
          Synset synset = node.getSynset();
          String term = synset.getWord(0).getLemma();
          parent.add(term);
          PointerTargetNodeList targets = new PointerTargetNodeList(synset.getTargets(PointerType.HYPERNYM) );
      if (targets.size() > 0) {
            parent = getHypernymTerm( targets, parent, term);
            }
        }

      }
      return parent;
    }
```

**First** of all you have to store the word in an array and rest of the code is as followed. if any one need the whole code then he/she can contact me at me g.mail: nabeelraza174

```
        for(int a = 0 ; a < strArray.length ; a++){
            FRUIT[a] = Dictionary.getInstance().getIndexWord(POS.NOUN, hyp[a]);
        }

        for(int b = 0 ; b < FRUIT.length  ; b++){
            ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
            arrayList.add(hyp[b]);

            PointerTargetTree printlist= demonstrateListOperation(FRUIT[b]);
            //printlist.print();
            PointerTargetNodeList ppt = printlist.getRootNode().getChildTreeList();
        string is ArrayList type
            ListClass temp = new ListClass();
            temp.string_list = getHypernymTerm(ppt, arrayList, hyp[b]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using Set to store all the Hypernyms then and Iterate over.

Answer (score -1):

Use [Wordnet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/).

Wordnet can be accessed using Java through its [Java API](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jwordnet/jwnl/1.4_rc3).
Before proceeding to APIs, first understand the structure of wordnet library on its portal.

Comment: i use it, but it is for only one word but i have multiple words which is stored in "string array". i want to get hypernyms of all those using loop.